# SQL 2008 backups failing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, backup, dbcc

I've an end user who came across this error and was asking for help. Not able to take full backups, below is the error we are getting. 
I tried running full backups to continue after errors but it still fails. Yes sql services has full access to the disk. I was able to take full backups for other databases on same server.

*Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Read on "R:\MSSQL10\Database.mdf" failed: 23(Data error (cyclic redundancy check).)
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.*

I ran checkdb it came back saying to run repair_allow_data_loss. Is there anyway to fix this error without running allow data loss?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time CRC error (cyclic redundancy check) is connected to file corruption (for any reason), it can be hard disk error (file written on bad sector of hard disk), it is possible to be something else as well.

What you can do is to take database offline for a second (Tasks>Take offline) than copy database and log files .mdf and .ldf to alternate location.
Than try to repair database, if there is some data lost, you can always restore copied files and database to previous state.

If your hard drive is damaged there is possibility that you will not be able to copy files.